# Prolog write predicate that decrements all elements of a list of integers

Tags: list, prolog

as the title suggests, I have to write a predicate that decreases all the values of a list. I did this but I am not convinced can you help me?

```Prolog
decremento([ ],[ ]).
decremento([H | T], L):- decremento(T,N), L is N-1.
```

Comment: Why aren't you convinced?

Comment: And what does "decreases all the values of a list" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity how I wrote it, especially and the syntax I don't know if it's okay. if I have a list [1,2,3] the result must be: [0,1,2]

Comment: Does it produce the correct result? If not, what does it produce?

Comment: @Enigmativity maybe better this way?                                                              incList([],[],_).
incList([X | List],Value,[X2 | List2]) :- incList (List, Value, List2),  X2 is X - Value.

Comment: Maybe. Does that produce the correct result?

Comment: And where did `incList/3` come from? You started with `decremento/2`. That's a big change. How do I call `incList/3`?

Comment: If you do not want to install some Prolog implementation, you can use SWISH [https://swish.swi-prolog.org/example/kb.pl] to try it out. Start with formulating the right question corresponding to your example "if I have a list [1,2,3] the result must be: [0,1,2]".

Answer (score 1):

So the problem statement is to traverse a list of [presumably] numbers, decrementing each one?

So... something like this —

```
decremento( []     , []     ) .  % the list is empty, nothing to decrement
decremento( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- % the list is non-empty, so...
  Y is X-1,                      % - decrement the head of the list,
  decremento(Xs,Ys)              % - recurse down
  .                              % Simple!
```

Running the above:

```
decremento( [1,2,3] , X ).
```

yields the desired

```
X = [0, 1, 2]
```

But... what about the other way?

```
decremento(X,[0,1,2]).
```

Sadly, that give us

```
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [2] 1 is _1632-1
   [1] decremento([_1694|_1696],[1,2|...]) at  line 3
```

We need to do a little type checking to be it work both ways. So, something like this will work properly.

- `decremento([1,2,3],X)` yields `X = [0,1,2]`
- `decremento(X,[0,1,2])` yields `X = [1,2,3]`
- `decremento([1,2,3],[0,1,2])` yields `true`.

```
decremento( Xs, Ys ) :- nonvar(Xs), !, add_list(-1,Xs,Ys) .
decremento( Xs, Ys ) :- nonvar(Ys), !, add_list(+1,Ys,Xs).

add_list( _, []     , []     ) .
add_list( N, [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] ) :- Y is X+N, add_list(N,Xs,Ys).
```

Comment: This could have been `maplist(plus(-1), Xs, Ys)`. Go ahead try it.

Comment: It could be. But this is almost certainly a learning project. And the point is to learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: "to learn how to do it yourself" this is a slippery slope. before you know it you are writing compilers. there is nothing wrong with going down the rabbit hole but most people don't want to and are not able to.

Comment: @User9213: Everybody should know how to write a compiler. Especially in Prolog (makes it pretty easy).

Answer (score 1):

From the comment to another answer:

```
maplist(plus(-1), Xs, Ys)
```

```
?- maplist(plus(-1), [1,2,3], Ys).
Ys = [0, 1, 2].

?- maplist(plus(-1), Xs, [1,2,3]).
Xs = [2, 3, 4].

?- maplist(plus(-1), [1,X], [Y,2]).
X = 3,
Y = 0.
```